# Need help in understanding the solution for the convergence of the series!!!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've proved the convergence of this series(QUESTION-6 of Part B) by using Cauchy Root test,but when I looked at the solution of this I'm not getting what's he doing. http://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/mscappmath2012.pdf.

Solution=http://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/mscappmath2012-solutions.pdf
Please explain in detail.
         what I have done-
We have, 
$$a_n =\frac{(logn)^4}{n^2}$$
taking nth root both sides, we get
$$(a_n)^{1/n} =\frac{((logn)^4)^{1/n}}{{(n^2)}^{1/n}}$$
$$ \bbox[border:2px solid red]
{
\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{((logn)^4)^{1/n}}{{(n^2)}^{1/n}}
\qquad  
}$$

Comment: I don't think the Cauchy root test works for this series. Could you explain what you did in more detail?

Comment: He is showing that the series converges since it can be bounded by another convergent series. However he's missing a power 4 in the last inequality.

Comment: Please see MathJax formatting guidelines. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Farnight-you are right ,i've mistaken while taking log.

Comment: @ElliotG-thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution reminds you that the exponential function grows faster than any polynomial (immediately noticeable from the exponential series: All summands are positive for $x>0$ and one of them is $\frac1{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}\gg x^k$). By substitution this means than $x$ grows faster than any polynomial in $\ln x$. In particular $x\gg (\ln x)^8$ and hence $\sqrt x\gg (\ln x)^4$. Hence the summand $\frac{(\ln n)^4}{n^2}$ is $\ll \frac{\sqrt n}{n^2}=n^{-3/2}$. And we now that $\sum n^{-b}$ converges for all $b>1$.

Comment: -Can this be done with any covergence test for the infinite series